# KivyMD User created button, imported and used across multiple screens

Tags: import, dynamic, kivy, kivymd, multiple-screens

Thanks for taking a look.  I am trying to create a "widgetdesign.kv" file, which will house my user created widgets, like:

```
<AwesomeButton@Button>
    text: "MDRectangleFlatIconButton"
    icon: "language-python"
    line_color: 0, 0, 0, 0 #NO LINE
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    text_color: "white"
    md_bg_color: app.BACKGROUND3
```

I have multiple screens, multiple files (.py and .kv) and am trying to be able to import widgets off my "widgetdesign.kv" file into the different .kv screen files.  Below is a .kv file housing a single kivy designed screen.

Like:

```
<ValidateEmail>:
    name: 'validate_email'
    on_pre_enter: print("ValidateEmail.kv on_pre_enter in the intro_widget SM")
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        md_bg_color: app.BACKGROUNDCOLOR
        spacing: '20dp'
        padding: '20dp'
        MDLabel:
            text: "Check Email for Verification Number"
            halign: 'center'

        MDCard:
            border_radius: '20dp'
            radius: (20)
            elevation: 20
            padding: '20dp'
            spacing: '10dp'
            style: 'elevated' #"filled", "elevated", "outlined"
            #size: root.id.event_email.size
            ripple_behavior: True
            focus_color: "grey"
            md_bg_color: app.BACKGROUNDCOLOR2

            MDLabel:
                id: validateemail_email
                text: app.USEREMAIL
                size_hint: .8, None
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, "center_y": .5,}

            MDTextField:
                id: validateemail_number
                mode: "rectangle"
                icon_left: "numeric"
                hint_text: "Number"
                helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                helper_text: "Verification Number From Email"
                color_mode: "custom"
                line_color_focus: 1,0,1,1
                size_hint: .8, None
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, "center_y": .5,}
        AwesomeButton:
            text: "Validate Email"
            #size_hint: 1, None
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, "center_y": .5,}
            on_release:
                #root.manager.transition = NoTransition()
                root.validate_email(validateemail_number.text, app.USEREMAIL)
```

I have tried different iterations of:
#:import my_button kv.ButtonStyles
at the top of my .kv files, but cannot seem to get the widget to be accessable from the different kivy screens and their respective .kv files.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a file awesome_button.py

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
class AwesomeButton(Button):
    pass
Builder.load_string("""
<AwesomeButton>:
    text: "MDRectangleFlatIconButton"
    icon: "language-python"
    line_color: 0, 0, 0, 0 #NO LINE
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    text_color: "white"
    md_bg_color: app.BACKGROUND
""")
```

And now you can use the class AwesomeButton like this

```
#: import AwesomeButton awesome_button.AwesomeButton
<ValidateEmail>:
    name: 'validate_email'
    on_pre_enter: print("ValidateEmail.kv on_pre_enter in the intro_widget SM")
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        md_bg_color: app.BACKGROUNDCOLOR
        spacing: '20dp'
        padding: '20dp'
        MDLabel:
            text: "Check Email for Verification Number"
            halign: 'center'

        MDCard:
            border_radius: '20dp'
            radius: (20)
            elevation: 20
            padding: '20dp'
            spacing: '10dp'
            style: 'elevated' #"filled", "elevated", "outlined"
            #size: root.id.event_email.size
            ripple_behavior: True
            focus_color: "grey"
            md_bg_color: app.BACKGROUNDCOLOR2

            MDLabel:
                id: validateemail_email
                text: app.USEREMAIL
                size_hint: .8, None
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, "center_y": .5,}

            MDTextField:
                id: validateemail_number
                mode: "rectangle"
                icon_left: "numeric"
                hint_text: "Number"
                helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                helper_text: "Verification Number From Email"
                color_mode: "custom"
                line_color_focus: 1,0,1,1
                size_hint: .8, None
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, "center_y": .5,}
        AwesomeButton:
            text: "Validate Email"
            #size_hint: 1, None
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, "center_y": .5,}
            on_release:
                #root.manager.transition = NoTransition()
                root.validate_email(validateemail_number.text, app.USEREMAIL)
```

Comment: Thanks mohamad aladdin.  I found that I was not loading the .kv file into my Builder.load_file.